# Problems With Percentage

Tags: c#

I am developing an app for a client. It should get some inputs from the console, like total meal price; plus, the second line should ask for the tip percentage. The third would ask for taxPercent.

I have the following code, but it fails one of two test cases. 
When I enter 15.50 for `mealCoast`, 15 percent for tip and 10% for tax, it passes the test case. However, if I enter 12.00 for `mealCost`, 20 for tip% and 8 for tax percent, it fails to meet the test case requirements.

Here you can see my code sample.

```
double mealCoast = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int tipPercent = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int taxPercent = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        //Calculating % 
        tipPercent = Convert.ToInt16(mealCoast) * (tipPercent) / 100;
        taxPercent = Convert.ToInt16(mealCoast) * (taxPercent) / 100;

        int totalCast = Convert.ToInt16(mealCoast) + tipPercent + taxPercent;

        Console.WriteLine("The total meal cost is {0} dollars.", totalCast);

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: surely percentages is n / 100 * number_percent_wanted = result. Are tips taxable? are you sure?

Comment: Add your inputs *with the expected and actual outputs*. What does your test case actually look like?

Comment: As a side note [Decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) is more suited to handling currency that `double`.

Comment: you cast double to integer, it could work for 12.00, but not for 15.5 (you get 16 and you result is wrong)

Comment: use `tipPercent = (int)(mealCoast * tipPercent / 100.0);`

Comment: You are casting to `int` all over the place which makes no sense. Casting doesn't round, it truncates. So keep everything in `double` (or better yet `decimal`) until you have your final result and then `Round` if needed. As it currently stands, you `15.50` test case doesn't make any sense. It returns `18` which is way off (it should be 19.38 rounded to the nearest cent)

Comment: first test case user enters 15.50 total meal 15 for 15 % tip then 10 for tax percent finally it sums up to 19 usd however second case 12.00 for mealPrice , 20 for tip and 8 for tax fails to produce required output output should be 15 usd it prints 14 usd strange thing taxtPercent variable become 0

Comment: Are you sure the 15.50 line truly comes out correct? as it told me 19 dollars. simple maths says 15.5/100 = .155, * 15 = 2.325, *10 = 1.55, so 15.5 +2.325+1.55 = 19.375 - your app clearly fails on the first too

Comment: **Never** use a floating-point type (`double` or `float`) to represent currency. **Always** use `decimal`.

Comment: tax can be  a decimal too - for years in the uk it was 17.5%

Comment: *"strange thing taxtPercent variable become 0"*, of course it does, because `12*8 = 98` and `98 / 100 = 0` when you do **integer division**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of possible issues:

Firstly, beware of the integer division. It basically means that if you divide `int` data type by `int` data type, you will get `int` result. Note that you use `int` all over the places, which is not a good practice - in your application, likely you don't want that. But rather you want to be precise in your money-involved computation. Thus, I suggest to use `double` - or better - `decimal` for your data computation

Secondly, beware of the non-convertible `string` to the respective number data type (be it `int` or floating point like `double`). Don't use `Parse`, but use `TryParse` to ensure the input is convertible.

By using correct data type and correct way to process the data, you would already half-way accomplishing your goals. Putting them into code, this is how it may look like:

```
decimal mealCoast, tipPercent, taxPercent; //use decimal, probably is best
bool mealCoastResult = decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out mealCoast);
bool tipPercentResult = decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out tipPercent); //use TryParse
bool taxPercentResult = decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out taxPercent);

//Input checking, check any parsing error
if (!mealCoastResult || !tipPercentResult || !taxPercentResult){
    //do some error handlers
    return; //probably don't continue is good
}
//you could also put some while loop

//Calculating % 
tipPercent = mealCoast * tipPercent / 100;
taxPercent = mealCoast * taxPercent / 100;

decimal grandTotal = mealCoast + tipPercent + taxPercent;
Console.WriteLine("The total meal cost is {0} dollars.", grandTotal);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: You should probably either `Round` `grandTotal` to 2 d.p. or perhaps `Floor` it, since you can't really expect people to pay in fractions of a cent.

Comment: @MattBurland ah yes, when it is used for payment, probably 2 decimal points would most probably be sufficient

Comment: Thanks Ian it worked Just rounded gandTotal  both test cases passed but really how stupid i was

Comment: @Dev ah yes, your mistake is a *very common* mistake, in fact. Also, note Matt Burland comment above. If you use `grandTotal` for payment, rounding up to the 2 decimal point is actually OK.

Answer (score 1):

> however second case 12.00 for mealPrice , 20 for tip and 8 for tax fails to produce required output output should be 15 usd it prints 14 usd strange thing taxtPercent variable become 0

Let's have a look at your code for the example:

```
double mealCoast = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // mealCoast = 12.
int tipPercent = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // tipPercent = 20
int taxPercent = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // taxPercent = 8

//Calculating % 
// Convert.ToInt16(mealCoast) will give you 12
// you are using integer division here, no digits preserved after period.
tipPercent = Convert.ToInt16(mealCoast) * (tipPercent) / 100; // 12 * 20 / 100 = 2
taxPercent = Convert.ToInt16(mealCoast) * (taxPercent) / 100; // 12 * 8 / 100 = 0

// 12 + 2 + 0 = 14
int totalCast = Convert.ToInt16(mealCoast) + tipPercent + taxPercent; // 14
Console.WriteLine("The total meal cost is {0} dollars.", totalCast); 

Console.ReadKey();
```

`/` operator is integer division if its operands are of integer types. It will **truncate** all the decimal digits after period. This also does not depend on the type of the variable you are assigning result at. Take a look at `decimal` or `double` data types.